# Change default hover color of TableRow MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hover, styles, tablerow

I would like to change the default hover color of a MUI TableRow by adding styles to the TableRow.

This question has been asked before, but the solutions are 3-4 years old, and they aren't working for me in my case.  The [docs](https://mui.com/api/table-row/) also make it seem like there shouldn't be such arduous workarounds to achieve the goal.

The most relevant thread regarding solutions is [here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/814).  At best, I can change the color of the hover for a cell, but not the whole row.

Below is my code; included you will find all of my attempts commented out:

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useCallback } from 'react';
import { makeStyles, TableCell, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core';
import EditIcon from '../../assets/common/edit-icon.svg';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { COLORS } from '../../constants/theme';
import { format } from 'date-fns';
import { Box } from '@material-ui/core';


const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  tableRow: {
    '& .MuiTableCell-root': {
      borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[200]}`,
      borderBottom: 'none',
      padding: 5,
      paddingTop: 8,
      paddingBottom: 8,
      cursor: 'pointer',
      minWidth: 25,
      //this works but only for cell hover, not the full row
      // "&:hover": {
      //   backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`,
      // },
    },
    //this doesn't work
    // hover: {
    //   backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`
    // },
    //this doesn't work
    // '& .MuiTableRow-hover': {
    //   backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`
    // },
    //this doesn't work
    // hover: {
    //   "&:hover": {
    //     backgroundColor: "green !important",
    //   },
    // },
    //this doesn't work
    // root: {
    //   '&:hover': {
    //     backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`
    //   },
    // },
    //this doesn't work
    // '& .MuiTableRow-hover': {
    //   backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`
    // },
    //this doesn't work
    // MuiTableRow: {
    //   root: {
    //     '&:hover': {
    //       backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`,
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    //this doesn't work
    // '& .MuiTableRow-root': {
    //   hover: { backgroundColor: "green !important" }
    // },
    // root: {
    //   '&:hover': {
    //     backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`
    //   },
    // },

    '& .MuiTableCell-root:first-child': {
      border: 'none'
    },
  },
  selectedRow: {
    backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`,
    '& .MuiTableCell-root': {
      color: COLORS.WHITE
    }
  },
  editIcon: {
    backgroundImage: `url(${EditIcon})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover',
    backgroundPosition: 'center',
    width: 18,
    height: 18
  }
}));

interface IProps extends Omit<unknown, 'children'> {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  isSelected: boolean;
  redirectTo: string;
  onSelect: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  cells: Array<string | number | Date | boolean | null | undefined>;
  id: string;
}

const TableRowComponent = ({
  isSelected,
  onSelect,
  redirectTo,
  cells,
  id
}: IProps): JSX.Element => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const getCorrectFormat = useCallback(
    cell => {
      return cell instanceof Date
        ? format(cell as Date, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mmaaaaa'm'")
        : cell;
    },
    [cells]
  );

  return (
    <TableRow
      className={classes.tableRow}
      classes={{ selected: classes.selectedRow }}
      selected={isSelected}
      onClick={() => onSelect(id)}
      hover={true}
    >
      <TableCell align="center">
        {isSelected && (
          <Link to={redirectTo}>
            <div className={classes.editIcon} />
          </Link>
        )}
      </TableCell>
      {cells.map(cell => (

        <TableCell key={(id + Math.random()).toString()} align="center">
          <Link to={redirectTo}>
            <Box>
              {cell || cell === 0 ? getCorrectFormat(cell) : 'null'}
            </Box>
          </Link>
        </TableCell>
      ))
      }
    </TableRow >
  );
};

export default TableRowComponent;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: re, your all tested methods, you dont need to do all this. if you are using chrome browser, rightclick the component and select inspect. then see which class is applied to that particular component then overide it with `sx` prop or `usestyles` also always check the API section of the component for CSS rules.  e.g. https://mui.com/api/table-row/

Answer (score 4):

check with below method. tested in MuiV5 and working for me. adjust according to your need. also you dont need to add `hover={true}` just `hover` is sufficient.

**Option1 : with sx props**

```
<TableRow
  ...
  hover
  sx={{
    '&.MuiTableRow-root:hover':{
      backgroundColor: 'red' 
    },
   }}
>
  ...
</TableRow>
```

**option 2: with `useStyles`**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  tableRow: {
    ...
    '&.MuiTableRow-root:hover':{
      backgroundColor: 'red' ,
    },
  },
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses!  Is there no way to achieve this using styling in the ```tableRow```?  If it's relevant, package.json lists my mui as  ```@material-ui/core": "4.11.4" ```

Comment: Yes, you can use it with `useStyles` updated answer to include `useStyles` method

Comment: the code you included as ***option 2*** does not work :/

Comment: If I drop an ```sx``` prop I get a ```No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: { component: ElementType<any>; } & { hover?: boolean | undefined; selected?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<TableRowTypeMap<{}, "tr">> & Pick<...>): Element', gave the following error.
    Property 'component' is missing in type '{ children: (Element | Element[])[]; className: string; classes: { selected: string; }; selected: boolean; onClick: () => void; sx: { '&.MuiTableRow-hover': { '&:hover': { backgroundColor: string; }; }; }; hover: true; }' but required in type '{ component: El...```

Comment: Perhaps more significant the error concludes with ```Property 'sx' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { hover?: boolean | undefined; selected?: boolean | undefined; } & CommonProps<TableRowTypeMap<{}, "tr">> & Pick<...>'. ```

Comment: I have tested both options with Mui V5 and V4 latest edition in codesandbox  and it worked for me. can you put your code in https://codesandbox.io/. I will check

Answer (score 1):

Using MUI `v5.3.0`:

You can change the color with the `sx` property like this:

```
<TableRow
  sx={{
    '&.MuiTableRow-hover': {
      '&:hover': {
        backgroundColor: 'papayawhip',
      },
    },
  }}
  hover
>
  ...
</TableRow>
```

haven't tried it but I guess you can use this as well in your `useStyles`

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked with `useStyles` was to add

```
 "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`,
    },
```

into the tableRow.  It seems kinda naked...but it works.

Full context in `useStyles` below

```
 const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      tableRow: {
        '& .MuiTableCell-root': {
          borderRight: `1px solid ${theme.palette.grey[200]}`,
          borderBottom: 'none',
          padding: 5,
          paddingTop: 8,
          paddingBottom: 8,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          minWidth: 25,
        },
        //this worked
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`,
        },
        '& .MuiTableCell-root:first-child': {
          border: 'none'
        },
      },
      selectedRow: {
        backgroundColor: `${COLORS.BLUE} !important`,
        '& .MuiTableCell-root': {
          color: COLORS.WHITE
        },
        '& ..MuiTableRow-root.Mui-selected': {
          hover: { backgroundColor: 'red' }
        }
      },
      editIcon: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${EditIcon})`,
        backgroundSize: 'cover',
        backgroundPosition: 'center',
        width: 18,
        height: 18
      }
    }));
```

I'm not sure why seemingly better/more logical options did not work.

Comment: glad, you solved your issue. Happy coding :)